# Build in library's to perform effective searching on 100GB files

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Is there any build-in library in Java for searching strings in large files of about 100GB in java. I am currently using binary-search but it is not that efficient.

Comment: Tell us about the 100GB dataset. What does it consist of, arbitrary strings? Are those strings arranged in a particular way? Are you allowed to pre-process the dataset? What kind of searches do you need to perform, exact matches of entire strings? As it stands, the problem is *way* underspecified.

Comment: @aix Thanks for replying. The dataset consists of arbitary strings. Yes I want to do exact matching on the entire string

Comment: If the data line oriented than think about using MapReduce...in particular in that data size.

Comment: My problem is that I don't want to use hadoop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know Java does not contain any file search engine, with or without an index. There is a very good reason for that too: search engine implementations are intrinsically tied to both the *input data set* and the *search pattern format*. A minor variation in either could result in massive changes in the search engine.

For us to be able to provide a more concrete answer you need to:

- Describe *exactly* the data set: the number, path structure and average size of files, the format of each entry and the format of each contained token.
- Describe *exactly* your search patterns: are those fixed strings, glob patterns or, say, regular expressions? Do you expect the pattern to match a full line or a specific token in each line?
- Describe *exactly* your desired search results: do you want exact or approximate matches? Do you want to get a position in a file, or extract specific tokens?
- Describe *exactly* your requirements: are you able to build an index beforehand? Is the data set expected to be modified in real time?
- Explain *why* can't you use third party libraries such as Lucene that are designed exactly for this kind of work.
- Explain *why* your current binary search, which should have a complexity of `O(logn)` is not efficient enough. The only thing that *might* be be faster, with a constant complexity would involve the use of a hash table.

It might be best if you described your problem in broader terms. For example, one might assume from your sample data set that what you have is a set of words and associated offset or document identifier lists. A simple method to approach searching in such a set would be to store an word/file-position index in a hash table to be able to access each associated list in constant time.

Answer (score 0):

If u doesn't want to use the tools built for search, then store the data in DB and use sql.